# Windows 3.11 maximized shell window in SYSTEM.INI when running it in DOSBox

Tags: windows, shell, emulation, dosbox, windows-3.1

I use a way to run 16-bit applications by running them in emulated Windows 3.11 in DOSBox. I automatically mount the directory containing the application, set the `SHELL` property in `SYSTEM.INI` to the path to the application, and then run `WIN.COM`.

It successfully starts Windows 3.11 and uses my application as the shell program, and thus it exits when I close it.

But I want to start my application in maximized window without seeing the background of the desktop. How can I do it?